# How to make a custom layout in a subtheme from omega 4 Drupal show in appearance settings?

Tags: drupal, layout, drupal-themes

I've started working with the omega 4 theme in drupal, switching from omega 3. I've created a subtheme succesfully, and according to the documentation I want to make my own layout. I've copied over the "Simple" layout from omega to my subtheme folder, as well as the required css and sass files. I've renamed all instances of Simple to Grid (my layout name).

That all seems fine, but when I go into my drupal installation, appearance -> settings -> layouts I still only see the four main omega layouts (simple, divine, hero, off canvas). It claims to show any layout from omega or installed subthemes. Why won't my layout show up for selection?

Additionally: Is it possible to use a different layout for the front page than the rest of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem myself and it turned out that in MY.layout.inc I forgot to changhe the value

```
template = simple-layout
```

with

```
template = MY-layout
```

Answer (score 0):

[pamatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995493/pamatt): BONUS! I was having the same problem. This fixes it.

A little more detail:

If you follow the directions [here](https://drupal.org/node/1936980) it's possible you might miss this explicit reference. I'm updating that page now.

Go to your

```
themename/layouts/layoutname/layoutname.layout.inc
```

file (of course, substitute "*themename*" and "*layoutname*" with the appropriate names) and look for a line that starts with "*template*" i.e.,

```
template = simple-layout
```

change "*simple-layout*" to your whatever you named your tpl file, minus the ".tpl.php" part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming back to this question since after a long absense of coding I came back to it this weekend and had the exact same problem! Above answers are correct.

Another issue I had was that I had to clear the cache from Drupal -> Configuration -> Performance and not just my browser cache. After clearing the cache it showed up.